# Sass does not render css variables

Tags: sass

I have this line:

```
min-height: calc(100vh - var(--vh-offset, 0px));
```

but I'm not sure why it compiles to:

```
min-height: calc(100vh - 0px);
```

My goal is:

```
min-height: calc(100vh - var(--vh-offset, 0px));
```

so that I can update --vh-offset with javascript.

How can I say sass to let the line be as it is?

Comment: I tried to find an answer in StackOverflow, but could not find it. But I'm pretty sure it must be somewhere. Sorry if it is duplicated...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, guys, I found the problem. It's not a bug. I forgot that I'm using precss in webpack. 
Now deactivating fixed the problem

```
//laravel mix
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
// .options({ 
//  postCss: [
//  require('precss')() <--- this gave me the problem
//  ]
// })
```